# attempt to use LaTeX equation triggers error

Tags: python, matplotlib, latex

I tried generating an axis label with a LaTeX equation.  My code, which appears below, generated the following error:

> 'latex' is not recognized as an internal or 
>   external command, 
>   operable
>   program or batch file.

Any suggestion as to why this is happening and how to resolve will be appreciated.

```
import matplotlib
from matplotlib import pyplot
from numpy import linspace, pi, sin

matplotlib.rc('text', usetex=True)
matplotlib.rcParams['text.latex.preamble'] = [r'\boldmath']

fig= pyplot.figure(figsize=[8,7], dpi=120, facecolor=[1,1,1])

x= linspace(0, 2*pi, 101)
pyplot.plot(x, sin( 2*pi*sin(x) ))

pyplot.title("Iterated Sine Function")
pyplot.xlabel('$x$')
pyplot.ylabel(r'$\sin(2*\pi*\sin(x))')

pyplot.show()
```

Comment: What operating system are you using?  Is latex installed? And BTW: your "ylabel" is missing the closing `$` sign.

Comment: I'm using Windows.  Your question about whether LaTeX is installed hit the mark.  It wasn't installed.  Installing it resolved this issue.  Thanks!